# What can be said about the order of short Weierstrass curves with $a=1$ and $b=0$?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am looking at a elliptic curves of the form $E:y^2=x^3+x$, i.e. short Weierstrass curves wtih $a=1$ and $b=0$, defined over a field $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p$ being a safe prime. Somewhat interestingly, this is kind of an inverse Koblitz curve (where $a=0$ and $b\ne0$).

Because $b=0$, the case of $x=0$ will always be a valid point of order 2 at $(0, 0)$.

1. As far as I can tell, such a curve has a necessary cofactor $h=2\cdot2$, but I can't seem to find the reason for another point of order 2.
2. Are there other things that can be said about the curve's order?

---

The reason this is of interest is because older Windows product key systems used curves of this particular form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve $E$ given by the equation $y^2 = x^3 + x$ is a Montgomery curve. Those are
are the form $By^2 = x^3 + Ax^2 + x$, so in this particular case we have $A=0$ and $B=1$.

The points of order $2$ have their $x$-coordinate as a root of $x^3 + x$. If $-1$ is a square over $\mathbf F_p$, then the points of order $2$ are $(0,0)$, $(\sqrt{-1},0)$ and $(-\sqrt{-1},0)$. Otherwise there is only $(0,0)$.

On those curves, the closest to a prime for the cardinality is $4\cdot\text{prime}$ for both the curve and its quadratic twist (such as the Goldilock curve), or $8\cdot\text{prime}$ and $4\cdot\text{prime}$ (such as Curve25519).

Answer (score 0):

**Claim:** If $p>5$ is a safe prime, then $\#E(\mathbb F_p)=p+1$.

*Proof:* Since $p$ is a safe prime, we have $p\equiv3\pmod4$. The curve $y^2 = x^3 + x$ over $\mathbb C$ has complex multiplication by $\mathbb Z[\mathrm i]$, given by the automorphism $(x,y) \mapsto (-x, \sqrt{-1}\cdot y)$. As every $p\equiv3\pmod4$ is inert in $\mathbb Z[\mathrm i]$, the reduction modulo $p$ is supersingular. By definition, this means $p\mid t$, where $t:=p+1-\#E(\mathbb F_p)$. Due to the Hasse bound $\lvert t\rvert \leq 2\sqrt p$, the only possibility is $t=0$.